# How does getopt() know when to stop?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have something that looks like this:

```
while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != EOF) { ... }
```

I might call the function like this:

```
./foo -d "my house" -t some more thoughts
```

Somehow getopt() knows that -d and -t are options, but after that it knows that 'some' 'more' and 'thoughts' are for later on.  What does getopt() look for to know that it's done processing args?  What is EOF?

Comment: `getopt` is not returning `EOF`. The usage is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Presumably it looks for something that does not start with a `-`?

Comment: It's done processing args because it looked at the number of arguments you told it to (`argc`) and pulled out the ones it cared about (`-d <value>` and `-t`)

Comment: You told `getopt` what the valid options were with `"d:t"`. If your question is about how to write a parser, that is too broad of a question. `getopt` returns `-1`, while `EOF` may be any negative value (implementation defined).

Comment: [BSD's getopt](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c). [GNU's getopt](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/getopt.c.html#getopt).

Comment: The obvious answer is `argc` contains the *argument count* and you tell `getopt` what arguments to look for. It will stop processing when the *argument count* is reached and if it hasn't found your mandatory arguments, you handle the error.

Comment: That is an undefined behaviour. Try using `\n` or `\0` instead of `EOF`. EOF is used to denote end of file . Here it there is no end apparently. You can also try `-1` or any negative value for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, using `EOF` with `getopt()` is just wrong (and "happens" to work on systems using `-1` for `EOF`). Use `-1`.

For your other question:

> What does getopt() look for to know that it's done processing args?

The answer is quite simple. `getopt()` **requires** that your program is called with options *before* other arguments. So it will stop when it first finds

- either `NULL` (indicating the end of `argv[]`) or alternatively when `argc` is reached (depending on the implementation) or
- an argument that doesn't start with `-` and that wasn't consumed by a `:` in your configuration string.

Comment: EOF is a bit more than a coincidence; it was the original documented return value for getopt, see for example 4.4BSD [getopt.c](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c) and [man page source](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.3) but POSIX changed it.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: And the change was made when `getopt()` was moved from `<stdio.h>` (where sonme systems declared it because people using it needed EOF) to `<unistd.h>` (which doesn't define EOF).  See the rationale section of the POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html).